# Replacing cells in a data frame

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

Let's say I have such a data frame with columns `X, Y, Z, T` and over 100 rows:

```
order X Y Z T
 i    a k b n
 j    c a b n
```

As you see, if `i-th X` and `j-th Y` have the same value (i.e `a`), then `i-th Z` and `j-th Z` have the same value (`b`) and `i-th T` and `j-th T` have the same value (`n`)

What I want to do is that if `i-th X` and `j-th Y` have the same value (i.e `a`), then `i-th Z = b` and `j-th Z = n` and `i-th T = n`, `j-th T = b`

```
order  X Y Z T
   i   a k b n
   j   c a n b
```

I have tried doing this in R by using `if else` and `for` loop, but I couldnt.

Can anyone help me do that in R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with `case_when`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>% 
   mutate(Z = case_when(lag(X) == Y~ T, TRUE ~ Z),
          T = case_when(lag(X) == Y ~ lag(Z), TRUE ~ T))
```

-output

```
df1
#  order X Y Z T
#1     i a k b n
#2     j c a n b
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(order = c("i", "j"), X = c("a", "c"), Y = c("k", 
"a"), Z = c("b", "b"), T = c("n", "n")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun. It works, but when I use `df1$Z`  or `df1$T`, it produces the former values: `b b` and `n n `, not the replaced ones. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Günal you need to assign (`df1 <- df1 %>%...`) to modify the original object

Comment: Done. Thanks a million.